# How to Read Complex XML file using Xlinq

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

Hi I am working on some XML files where I am using Xlinq to traverse through the XMl file. I have mentioned below the structure of the XML file :

```
<abc_classes>
  <abc:class xsi:type="bbb" id="123">
    <status>66</status>
    <source_language country_code="US" language_code="en" />
    <preferred_name>
      <label country_code="EN" language_code="en">Horse</label>
    </preferred_name>
    <abc_position>14</abc_position>
  </abc:class>
  <abc:class xsi:type="bbb" id="345">
    <status>66</status>
    <source_language country_code="US" language_code="en" />
    <preferred_name>
      <label country_code="EN" language_code="en">Elephant</label>
    </preferred_name>
    <abc_position>15</abc_position>
  </abc:class>
```

My work should display the result like :
Horse-14
Elephant-15

I need to do this using XLinq. Any will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple [Google search](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18751/XLINQ-Introduction-Part-3-Of-3) reveled much of the details about traversing, loading and so on. Please don't be lazy to read.